# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object

Tags: java, android, serialization

I try to send the following object between activities

```java
public class SerializablePlusCourtChemin implements Serializable {

    public static final String FROM = "From";
    public static final String TO = "Ro";
    public static final String BY= "By";

    private List<SerializableSalle> mSalles = new ArrayList<SerializableSalle>();
    private List<SerializableMouvement> mMouvements = new ArrayList<SerializableMouvement>();

    public List<SerializableSalle> getmSalles() {
        return mSalles;
    }

    public void setmSalles(List<SerializableSalle> mSalles) {
        this.mSalles = mSalles;
    }

    public List<SerializableMouvement> getmMouvements() {
        return mMouvements;
    }

    public void setmMouvements(List<SerializableMouvement> mMouvements) {
        this.mMouvements = mMouvements;
    }

}
```

I get the exception mentioned in the title the stacktrace is

```sh
RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = fr.cnam.nfa024.jpmena.geolocalisationindoor.bean.SerializablePlusCourtChemin)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = fr.cnam.nfa024.jpmena.geolocalisationindoor.bean.SerializablePlusCourtChemin)
        at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2215)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2064)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
        at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
        at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1295)
        at fr.cnam.nfa024.jpmena.geolocalisationindoor.ViewCourseActivity.onCreate(ViewCourseActivity.java:35)
.............................................
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: fr.cnam.nfa024.jpmena.geolocalisationindoor.bean.SerializableSalle;
Incompatible class (SUID): fr.cnam.nfa024.jpmena.geolocalisationindoor.bean.SerializableSalle: static
final long serialVersionUID =2285590632111183141L; but expected
fr.cnam.nfa024.jpmena.geolocalisationindoor.bean.SerializableSalle: static
final long serialVersionUID =-5659168454258435009L;
```

Before I add a Boolean to  *SerializableSalle* I didn't have any problem. I just added *accessible* to *SerializableSalle*, that makes:

```java
public class SerializableSalle implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private Integer identifiant;

    private Boolean accessible; //La salle est elle ouverte oou bien en travaux ?

    public SerializableSalle(Integer id, String name, Boolean accessible) {
        this.name = name;
        this.identifiant = id;
        this.accessible = accessible;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getIdentifiant() {
        return identifiant;
    }

    public void setIdentifiant(Integer identifiant) {
        this.identifiant = identifiant;
    }

    public Boolean getAccessible() {
        return accessible;
    }

    public void setAccessible(Boolean accessible) {
        this.accessible = accessible;
    }
}
```

- The problem disappear when I remove *accessible* from the *SerializableSalle*

(in french Salle means Room)

- any help ?
  Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: That error means the Serialized/De-serialized class signatures are different. Maybe you were calling "Apply Changes and Restart Activity" rather than totally restarting the app so the Intent bundle wasn't refreshed, or caching the old class somewhere and trying to load it in as the new class?

Comment: I uninstalled the app and launched it again and the problem disappeared. But I now face another difficulty as explained in that [new stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874377/pending-intent-does-not-fire)